# Using -f and -o cucumber flags with calabash

Tags: android, testing, jenkins, calabash, calabash-android

Hello I am currently trying to integrate calabash-android with Jenkins. I need to use the -f and -o flags to output the results to a json file in order to produce a human readable report.

This is the line I am using

```
calabash-android run "$WORKSPACE/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk" -f json -o testresult.json
```

Running this causes calabash-android to error out saying that there is no -f option and in turn causes the build to fail. This happens despite the results being written out to testresult.json

Does anyone know of a work around or perhaps a bug fix?

Edit: I recently found this only seems to happen on Linux. Running the command on OSX does not produce the error

Answer (score 0):

In our Jenkins pipeline we output in junit format like this:

```
 calabash-android run $APK --format junit --output report
```

And then publish the junit file

Comment: What version of calabash are you running? Does it give an invalid option error for --format and cause the build to report as failed? Are you running the shell command as a post build step?

Comment: calabash-android v0.7.3 and no it doesn't give any errors.  We run it as a build step and the publish junit report as a post build step